# vagrant - keyserver receive failed while installing openedx devstack

Tags: vagrant, edx, vagrant-provision, openedx

i'm trying to install openedx devstack on Windows 10 and Lubuntu 12.04;
with Vagrant 1.8.6 and VirtualBox 4.3 installed.
in windows i use [Babun Shell](http://babun.github.io) to run commands.

1. running Babun as Administator
2. mkdir devstack
3. cd devstack
4. export OPENEDX_RELEASE="open-release/eucalyptus.1"
5. curl -OL https://raw.github.com/edx/configuration/$OPENEDX_RELEASE/util/install/install_stack.sh
6. bash install_stack.sh devstack

After following instruction described in [open edx docs](http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-installing-configuring-and-running/en/latest/installation/devstack/install_devstack.html) i got key server error (in both OSs).

This is the error i'm facing at the end of installation process:

> [1;32m==> default: failed: [localhost] => {"cmd": "apt-key adv --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv 46095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
>   ==> default: stderr: gpg: requesting key D88E42B4 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
>   ==> default: gpg: keyserver timed out
>   ==> default: gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
>   ==> default: 
>   ==> default: stdout: Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --secret-keyring /tmp/tmp.lCcAGQG10R --trustdb-name /etc/apt/trustdb.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv 46095ACC8548582C1A2699A9D27D666CD88E42B4
>   ==> default: 
>   ==> default: msg: gpg: requesting key D88E42B4 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
>   ==> default: gpg: keyserver timed out
>   ==> default: gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error[0m
>   [1;32m==> default: 
>   ==> default: FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting[0m

and then:

> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
>   assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
>   should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
>   went wrong.

Please help me to figure out this issue.
Thanks alot.

Comment: _gpg: keyserver timed out_

sounds like a temporary issue - can you retry ?

Comment: I retried several times, but nothing happened .

Answer (score 0):

This is usually caused by your firewall blocking the port 11371. You could unblock the port in your firewall. In case you don't have access to the firewall you could either:

**Force it to use port 80 instead of 11371**

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 94558F59
```